# Django urls.py mistaking two close urls

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

i'm adding forms to my app to modify my lobbys (my custom model).

In **urls.py**, here is my urlpattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^lobbys/$', views.LobbyListView.as_view(), name='lobbys'),
url(r'^lobby/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$', views.LobbyDetailView.as_view(), name='lobby-detail'),
url(r'^lobby/create/$', views.LobbyCreate.as_view(), name='lobby_create'),
url(r'^lobby/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', views.LobbyUpdate.as_view(), name='lobby_update'),
url(r'^lobby/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', views.LobbyDelete.as_view(), name='lobby_delete'),
]
```

The problem is the following:

The third url is supposed to link to a single lobby template identifed with a UUID field as the primary key. Without the three last lines everything worked fine, but when I added my three urls for the forms, I'm getting the error

> Exception Value:    ["'create' is not a valid UUID."]

I understand urls.py is taking "create" as a primary key instead of considering it as an urls to an other view.

How can I bypass this problem? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django url config with multiple urls matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023708/django-url-config-with-multiple-urls-matching)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the ordering of the url patterns

```
url(r'^lobby/create/$', views.LobbyCreate.as_view(), name='lobby_create'),
url(r'^lobby/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$', views.LobbyDetailView.as_view(), name='lobby-detail'),
```

The issue is, since `lobby-detail` is looking for a alphanum pattern, it also matches the pattern `lobby/create`. The order matters in the regex patterns, so `lobby_create` is never matched. By changing the order, the issue would be resolved